# Sticky tape around stuff

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, geometry, shrinkwrap

[image]

I tried few tutorials , followed some tips on the subject , tried shinrkwrap / simulation / modeling / geometry nodes / editing / curves but i can never achieve the effects i want because of my lack of knowledge on the subject and the lack of information on the web..

Can someone actually show me the way to make sticky tape around object pressing closely against it following perfectly it's topology?

Blend file : https://ufile.io/x3iztaml

Comment: Please don't use external sites with adverts to share your Blend file. Since it's under 30Meg in size you can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there.

Comment: Helo ! Hard to say with the tiny snippet but I think what you want to do is use a shrinkwrap modifier THEN a solidify modifier. Remember to subdivide your tape object enough so that it can bend without being ugly

Comment: Not exactly the same, but maybe some clues [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/277188/35559)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can fix it with the current topology, but it will work better if you simplify the topology of your bag (with the remesh tool):

[image]

Same thing for the tape topology (simplified with the *Checker Deselect* tool):

[image]